# Selenium get size of transferred data (resoures size)

Tags: java, selenium, google-chrome-devtools

I want to get size of whole page using Selenium.
Using this piece of code:

```
for (LogEntry entry : driver.manage().logs().get(LogType.PERFORMANCE)) {
    if(entry.getMessage().contains("Network.dataReceived")) {
        Matcher dataLengthMatcher = Pattern.compile("encodedDataLength\":(.*?),").matcher(entry.getMessage());
        dataLengthMatcher.find();
    }
```

I can get the transferred data size, but i want the uncompressed size like in Resources section of Chrome Dev tools:
[Chrome Dev Tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KO4nC.png)

What is the difference between encodedDataLength and dataLength? Is dataLength solution for my problem?

Thanks

Comment: Do you got any data `with driver.manage().logs().get(LogType.PERFORMANCE)`? Could you update your question and provide json with message?

Comment: LogType.DRIVER works every time for me not PERFORMANCE